# Flex custom style (skin)

Tags: apache-flex, coding-style, adobe, skin

How can I modify standart style of progress bar controll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full control over the style, you can create your own programmatic skins and replace the default skins.  Look at ProgressBarSkin, ProgressBarIndeterminateSkin, ProgressBarMaskSkin and ProgressBarTrackSkin in the SDK to see how they are drawn by default.  You can then create your own versions of those skin files and draw them however you like.  Then you just set those skin files to your ProgressBar.  You can do that directly in MXML, or set it in CSS to change all of the ProgressBars in your app.  Hope that helps.